# SQL connection timeout error with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am updating the 2600 records in a `table` at once with `entity framework`.

It was working previously but now suddenly started throwing the `timeout error` every time.

The `timeout` property is set to 150.

Also, multiple users are using the `application` at the same time.

**Below is the `code`:**

```
    foreach (var k in context.Keywords.Where(k => k.CurrentDailyCount > 0))
            {
               k.CurrentDailyCount = 1;
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
```

**This is the `error` I'm facing:**

[image]

[image]

What can be the issue behind this `error`? It was working fine but suddenly started throwing the `timeout error`.

Comment: Have you verified it's not running into some sort of DB lock?  view the generated SQL commands to see if it hangs at any specific entity or is it just slow and timing out after 150 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

```
var entries = context.Keywords.Where(k => k.CurrentDailyCount > 0) ?? new List<Keyword>(); 
foreach (var k in entries)
{
   k.CurrentDailyCount = 1;
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

1. Store the filtered keywords in a variable to **save time** it takes to search:
   `context.Keywords.Where(k => k.CurrentDailyCount > 0)`
2. Ensure
   filtered keywords is **never null**: `?? new List<Keyword>()`.
3. Save records **Asynchronously**: `await context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: It seem that your code won't succeed to compile .  Also , storing the `context.Keywords.Where(k => k.CurrentDailyCount > 0)` to a variable will not save time because of the lazy loading feature .

Comment: Unless you are using .NET 2.0 and visual studio 2005, the code should compile. just make sure your method is decorated with `async` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you may consider to select only primaryKey field and CurrentDailyCount. you can make it like

```
context.Keywords.Select(x => new Keyword(){
   PrimaryKeyColumn = x.primaryKeyColumn,
   CurrentDailyCount = x.currentDailyCount 
}).Where(k => k.CurrentDailyCount > 0)
```

And also you should check the execution time of your sql statement. If CurrentDailyCount column is not indexed, it is no surprise that your Code gets timeout error.

> The timeout property is set to 150.

Which timeout are you addressing? is it SQL Connection Timeout or Kestrel Server timeout? If you set SQL timeout period to 150 and the kestrel timeout value is default (Which is 120s) your code interrupts when it reaches to 120 seconds.